# VS2010 Only show file names in tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My website has several nested folders and sometimes long file names, so sometimes only 4 tabs can be opened at a time.

1. Can vs2010 be made to show only file names and leave out any path information?
2. Can the max displayed length for tabs be set?

I know the window can be split so top and bottom both have their own tabs.

For example (using the ["Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools"](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)):

[image]

Showing the files:

- **...r.aspx.cs**
- **...s.aspx.cs**
- **...s.aspx.cs**
- **...s.aspx.cs**
- **...s.aspx.cs**

For example (not using the Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools):

[image]

Showing the files:

- **Adminstration/...quests.aspx.cs**
- **Adminstration/...tUsers.aspx.cs**
- **Adminstration/...ctions.aspx.cs**
- **Adminstration/...eBanks.aspx.cs**

Comment: Visual Studio is driving me up the wall with this. i wish there was a solution. VS, and its variants (i.e. SSMS) suffer the problem that once you've switched to a different tab you need to consider the original tab lost (you can never find it again).

Comment: *(8 days later)* Visual Studio is driving me nuts with this. i wish there was a solution. i'm going out of my mind.

Comment: (19 days later) Visual Studio is driving me nuts with this. i wish there was a solution. i'm going out of my mind.

Comment: This is default mode in visual studo 2012 :)

Comment: Default as in defaults to broken, or default as in default fixed?

Comment: :) the this is now fixed in the default mode. The full path is shown as a tooltip when you hover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try installing the "Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools" extension from the Extension Manager in VS.  It adds a new section to the standard option dialogue that allows you to customise what they call the "Document Tab Well."

It doesn't let you truncate the filename, but you can change the way they draw and scroll, which might be enough to help.

Answer (score 7):

It does allow more tabs at a time, but it severly shortens the amount of file name you see. So while it allows editing more files, you won't know what file you are editing.

For now I'm using the trial version of [Tab Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/index.htm)

Comment: I like tab studio, it actually solves the question above. I've used visual studio 2010 pro power tools but it's not a sufficient solution. Wonder if there's a free alternative to Tab studio... it's too much a price to pay for what they're charging for it.

Comment: You can change the behaviour of the tabs, including multiple rows and setting widths.  Also: $49 for Tab Studio?  Really?!

Answer (score 1):

In VS2010, go to Tools - Extension Manager. Go to the online gallery and search for this extension:

Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools

This extension, once installed, gives you extensive control over the document well, including setting a max tab width and much more. I love this extension, and have had zero issues customizing tab behavior to suit my preferences. Hope this helps.

Comment: See the screenshot above showing a screenshot with the **Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools** installed; and it still showing folder names; truncating filenames as a result.

Answer (score 1):

## Fixed in Visual Studio 2012

This has finally been fixed in Visual Studio 2012:

[image]

So i see:

- **PendingRequests.aspx**  (rather than **...r.aspx.cs**)
- **ImportUsers.aspx.cs**  (rather than **...s.aspx.cs**)
- **SearchTransactions.aspx.cs**  (rather than **...ctions.aspx.cs**)
- **ImportTimeBanks.aspx.cs**  (rather than **eBanks.aspx.cs**)

Now if we could just get the entire Visual Studio ecosystem to:

- return to the use of **Left**, **Right** arrows to navigate overflow tabs
- open new tabs on the right

[image]

just like Windows has been doing in 1994, and Visual Studio would start to almost become a user-friendly Windows application.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using this excellent extension for VS2010 that solve your problems: [Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20110119025922/http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).

It is a bundle of several extensions, but the most notable for you is the [Document Well 2010 Plus](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/document-well-2010-plus-hidden-options/). It allows you to configure the document tabs: to be the constant width, colour-coded by project, pinned, etc...

You can toggle the extensions that you do not want by editing the manifest file in:
`~\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Extensions\Microsoft\Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools\`

---

**@IanBoyd:** I agree, it doesn't solve the problem 100% however it helps (which is why most of the answers to this question suggest it). With the *Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools* add-on you can **a)** set the maximum tab width using one tab options, **b)** setup some colour categorizing rules to help differentiate between projects/file types.

In VS2010, my workflow relies upon several add-ons and keyboard shortcuts to manage my workspace; for example I use <kbd>CTRL + Tab</kbd> to switch between active documents, use the pin-tab feature and colour coding from *Power Pro Tools*, the open solution file dialog from [Visual Assist X](https://www.wholetomato.com/), and re-open last edited file from [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: Amended the original question with a screenshot showing *Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools* not solving the problem.

Comment: Updated answer with reply. :)

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered already here:
[Remove path from tab name in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715426/remove-path-from-tab-name-in-visual-studio-2010)

Install the productivity power tools extension and it should do it by default!

Cheers.

Comment: The accepted answer there says that it cannot be done, *"The truncating behavior still occurs. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a setting that controls the text on the tabs. It appears the method of truncating has been changed since VS2008, but I don't think it completely resolves your issue."*. And the other answer suggests using the **Productivity Power Tools** can "take care of this". Notice the screenshot in this question showing the **Productivity Power Tools** not taking care of it.